# Mysql ResultsetMapping for Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am using a procedure in spring mvc. I want to do a sqlresultsetmapping for the result the procedure will be returning. The procedure won't be returning any entites related result. How can i do the sqlresultsetmapping for the procedure.

Sql Mapping written in declared class emp :

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "sampleemp", classes = {
 @ConstructorResult(targetClass = emp.class,
 columns = { @ColumnResult(name = "id"),
             @ColumnResult(name = "name"),
             @ColumnResult(name = "department"),
           })
 })
```

NamedStoredProcedureQuery written in the same class emp:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "employee", procedureName = "sample", parameters =
 { @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "id", type = Integer.class),
   @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "name", type = String.class),
   @StoredProcedureParameter(mode  = ParameterMode.IN, name= "department", type = String.class)
 },
 resultSetMappings = { "sampleemp" })
```

How to map these from DAO layer when calling the stored procedure using the below code:

```
StoredProcedureQuery spQuery = (StoredProcedureQuery) entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("sample")
 .registerStoredProcedureParameter("id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
 .registerStoredProcedureParameter("name", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
 .registerStoredProcedureParameter("department", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
 .setParameter("id", id)
 .setParameter("name", name)
 .setParameter("department", dept);

spQuery.execute();
```

Comment: Show your procedure and also code that you have tried to resolve the problem.

Comment: Add it in question and format it properly. Please don't add it in comments.

Comment: @KeyurPanchal added in question format

Answer (score 0):

1) ConstructorResult implies that you have constructor with the same fields (order matter)

I prefer @EntityResult. This also needs a constructor but with no args.

2) I could not make it work with createStoredProcedureQuery so I called

```
final Query query1 = entityManager.createNativeQuery("call yourProcName(PARAMS)", "NAME_OF_SqlResultSetMapping");
 List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
```

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-sql-resultset-mapping